# Is webmasters an okay place to ask about how to sell a domain?

Tags: support, suitable-question

I have a domain registered in several TLDs (com, eu, net, de....) from a  project that never came to fruition.

I'm dissolving my business at the moment. The domain in question is a fine, five-letter name, so I would like to see them sold, at least to get back the registration fees I paid for them over the past few years. However, putting them on Sedo.com didn't yield much success.

Is it a fair question to ask for specific tips and additional places to sell these domains  on Webmasters.SE?

If yes, how should I word it? Can I mention the domain in question (which obviously would be my favourite choice) or should I put it in general terms?

Answer (score 3):

I feel: Its definitely okay to ask for suggestions. There are questions in similar spirit here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain-names

It might not be okay to post an ad for sale though :D